# error when use NextResponse.json router handler of next js 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I encountered a problem when using router handler in next js 14, the problem is as follows:

node current version: 21.6.1
nextjs: 14.1.0

[router handler code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9W6l.png)

```
⨯ TypeError: l.json is not a function
at g (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/route.js:1:2707)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:42484
at async eI.execute (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:32486)
at async eI.handle (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:43737)
at async Y (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:16:24556)
at async Q.responseCache.get.routeKind (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:17:1025)
at async r3.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:17:507)
at async r3.renderPageComponent (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:17:4780)
at async r3.renderToResponseImpl (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:17:5363)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Typescript version. If its 5.2 or above, use `Response.json()` instead of `NextResponse.json()`

you can check the latest Next JS sample snippet [Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#behavior)

Comment: no , i don't use Typescript , i use javascript